# Bootstrap элемент вылезает за пределы

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть панель:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel panel-body">Тут что-то</div>
            <div class="panel panel-footer">
                <span class="label label-default">Раз</span>
                <span class="label label-default">Раз</span>
                <span class="label label-default">Раз</span>
                Тут еще много сппанов, очень.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И получается проблема, потому-что вылезает за пределы `panel-footer` Вот картинка, как выглядит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Не хватает элемента с классом `row` между `container-fluid` и `col-*`.

Comment: К сожалению `row ` не помогает... Я каждую `panel` обернул в row

Comment: @Wolkodav, выше, а не ниже. Сказал же, между.

Comment: Не лучше, к сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

может быть так?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel panel-body">Тут что-то</div>
            <div class="panel panel-footer">
                <span class="label label-default">Раз</span>
                <span class="label label-default">Раз</span>
                <span class="label label-default">Раз</span>
                Тут еще много сппанов, очень.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тут все работает, проверил, и у вас не указаны размеры на mediascreen lg и xl

Comment: да, точно... не помешали бы `lg` и `xl`